# If $f$ is $+\infty$ on a set of positive measure and the integral exists in $[-\infty,+\infty]$, must the integral be $+\infty$?

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Suppose $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ is a measure space and $f$ a measurable function from $X$ to $[-\infty,+\infty]$. Suppose that $$\int_{X}f\ d\mu$$ exists in $[-\infty,+\infty]$, and that $X$ contains a measurable set $A$ on which $f=+\infty$.

My question is: if $\mu(A)>0$, can we say that $$\int_{X}f\ d\mu\stackrel{?}=+\infty$$ Why not? Thanks for your answer and comment.

Comment: What if $X$ contains $B$ where $f$ is $-\infty$ and $\mu(A)=\mu(B)$?

Comment: @Bhoot: Then $\int_X f\,d\mu$ will not exist.

Comment: If you assume $\int_X f d \mu$ exists and $\int_A f d \mu = +\infty$ for some $A \subset X$, then there is no $B \subset X$ such that $\int_B f d \mu = -\infty$, since then $\int_X f d \mu$ cannot exist. Consequently you do get that $\int_X f d \mu = \int_A f d\mu + \int_{X \setminus A} f d \mu = +\infty$ (the second term is either finite or $+\infty$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integral of $f$ is defined to be the integral of the positive part minus the integral of the negative part of $f$: $$\int_X f\,d\mu=\int_X f^{+}\,d\mu - \int_X f^{-}\,d\mu.$$ Your hypotheses imply that $\int_X f^{+}\,d\mu\geq \int_Af^{+}\,d\mu=+\infty$.  The fact that the integral exists as an element of $[-\infty,\infty]$ thus implies that the integral of the negative part is finite, and $\int_X f\,d\mu=+\infty$.